# How to add a new html table row each time mysql query is executed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering if it is possible to query a database, and each time a submit button is clicked, it will add a new row to the table, instead of refreshing the page.

You see, what's happening is that when I run the query, it will add the row successfully, but when I run the query again, it will refresh the page, essentially only being able to add only one row at a time.

Basically, I want to be able to create a table which will add a product to the list each time I scan a barcode with a barcode scanner. As the user scans the code, the query will execute to grab the relevant data from the database, and display a row.

```html
$barcode = $_POST["Barcode"];
$query = "Select * from products WHERE ProductBarcode = $barcode";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
     
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table>
 <tr>
     <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
     <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
     </tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['Row_ID']."' />".$row['Row_ID']."</td>
<td>".$row['ProductName']." "."</td></tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: You would probably need to use Jquery or Javascript to achieve that without refreshing page

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery/ajax to achieve this. Check out this post. I believe it has exactly what you're looking for: 
[Creating a table with mysql, php and ajax (with jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284073/creating-a-table-with-mysql-php-and-ajax-with-jquery)

Comment: hmmm yea something like what I want, but I want that 'get data' button to act as the submit button for a form, since the barcode will be entered by the user. So when that button is clicked, then the query will be executed to grab the data corresponding to the barcode entered.

Comment: Yeah, so onclick of the 'get data' button you call a javascript function. In this function you grab the data from the barcode field and send it via Ajax to your php script. You can package up parameters in your Ajax call then grab these parameters server side using php.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience using Ajax, and barely any Javascript experience lol...so I barely understand you xD Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Using Ajax

I'm writing an Psudo code which will give you and idea how to do this

Step 1: create a table and define table Id

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Step 2: Submit Your Barcode Data or product Id using Ajax

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', "#submitButton", function () {
var barcode = $("#barcode").val();
    $.ajax({
                url: 'getProduct.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'Barcode':barcode},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.products.length > 0) {
                   $(data.products).each(function(index,element){
                        $("#myTable").append("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' value='"+ element.product_id+"' />"+ element.product_id+"</td>
    <td>"+ element.product_name+"</td></tr>");
                   });
                } else {
                  alert("No Products Found");
                }  
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                showLoader();
            },
            complete: function () {
                hideLoader();
            },
        });
 });
</script>
```

Step 3: your getProduct.php Code will be like this

```
$barcode = $_POST["Barcode"];
$query = "Select * from products WHERE ProductBarcode = $barcode";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $products = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
} else {
    $products = [];
}
echo json_encode($products);
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, however, when I click the submit button, nothing happens.

Comment: try using alert("hello"); after $(document).on('click',

Comment: Nope...Same problem :(

Comment: See your browser console, solve if any errors are displaying there

Comment: No errors...but i'm probably not structuring everything correctly. Is it possible for you to help me out there?

Comment: Yes, I can help you in this

Comment: oh it says I need at least 20 reputation to talk there lol...sigh